# extract database information into table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make offer for my hosting company. I made a table with the offers:

```
CREATE TABLE `planes` (
  `id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `DiskSpace` text NOT NULL,
  `AnnuallyDataTransfer` text NOT NULL,
  `FTPAccounts` text NOT NULL,
  `EmailBoxes` text NOT NULL,
  `BandwidthAllowance` text NOT NULL,
  `FreeDomains` text NOT NULL,
  `MySQLDatabases` text NOT NULL,
  `price` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


INSERT INTO `planes` VALUES (1, '5GB', 'Unlimited', '25', '1000', 'Unlimited', '1', 'Unlimited', '200 LE');
INSERT INTO `planes` VALUES (2, '10 GB', 'Unlimited', '50', '1000', 'Unlimited', '1', 'Unlimited', '300');
```

Then I tried to show that offers in `php` codes. Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM planes ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,2") or die(mysql_error());
    $Disc = 1;
    echo '<table class="ranking">';
    echo '<tr><td class="rankhead">#</td><td class="rankhead">Plan1</td><td class="rankhead">Plan2</td><td class="rankhead">plan3</td></tr>';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )){
        $name =  $row['AnnuallyDataTransfer'];
        $Disc = $row['FTPAccounts'];
        $class = $row['EmailBoxes'];

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="rankvalues">'.$Disc.'</td>';
        echo '<td class="rankvalues">'.$name.'</td>';
        echo '<td class="rankvalues">'.$Disc.'</td>';
        echo '<td class="rankvalues">'.$class.'</td>';

        $Disc++;
        echo "</tr>"; 
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

But I got error design. I want to show all the offers field into the left as a column and offers on row and each offer has has it's value from the field on the left.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: What error occurs when you execute this script? Please give us more information. I see that the mysql_connect (please use PDO!) is missing, where do you connect to the database?

Comment: You're using the $Disc variable twice - as a counter, and as the value of $row['FTPAccounts'].

Comment: the problem that if u run the code u will see that the id is taken a column on the left i need to put the offer fields in it's place and each plan from the above row take it's value from the column

Comment: @Barmar please can u help me in this ?!

Answer (score 0):

you are using `$Disc` variable for such increament and database value  correct them

try this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )){
      $AnnuallyDataTransfer =  $row['AnnuallyDataTransfer'];
      $FTPAccounts = $row['FTPAccounts'];
      $EmailBoxes = $row['EmailBoxes'];

      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td class="rankvalues">'.$Disc.'</td>';
      echo '<td class="rankvalues">'.$AnnuallyDataTransfer.'</td>';
      echo '<td class="rankvalues">'.$FTPAccounts.'</td>';
      echo '<td class="rankvalues">'.$EmailBoxes.'</td>';

      $Disc++;
      echo "</tr>"; 
}
```

**NOTE :** `mysql_*` is deprecated use `mysqli_*` or `pdo`